# how to remove an object from an array if object value doesnt exist

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects and im trying to remove all objects in that array that dont have the data object in in them. Ive tried to use filter but not got it working.

```
results.filter(obj => obj.data === undefined)
```

```
results = [
{id: 1,
 location: 'a',
 data: {
   latlong: 456464,456465,
   value: 45},
 team: a},
{id: 2,
 location: 'f',
 data: {
   latlong: 12323,456465,
   value: 43},
 team: c},
{id: 3,
 location: 'a',
 team: a},
{id: 4,
 location: 'g',
 team: f}
]
```

How i want it to look

```
results = [
{id: 1,
 location: 'a',
 data: {
   latlong: 456464,456465,
   value: 45},
 team: a},
{id: 2,
 location: 'f',
 data: {
   latlong: 12323,456465,
   value: 43},
 team: c}
]
```

Comment: `filter` doesn't mutate the array but returns a new array. So, you need to reassign: `result = resut.filter(...)`. Also the condition should be `!== undefined`

Comment: Filter keeps the values for which the callback is true, so you want `results = results.filter(obj => obj.data)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use filter

```js
ndp = [ {id: 1, location: 'a', data: { latlong: "456464,456465", value: 45}, team: "a"}, {id: 2, location: 'f', data: { latlong: "12323,456465", value: 43}, team: "c"}, {id: 3, location: 'a', team: "a"}, {id: 4, location: 'g', team: "f"} ]

  console.log(ndp.filter(o=>o.data))
```